# Native Query mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using native query and I get a Tuple with a set of login, email, pass, regDate.
I also created a class with these attributes (This is not an Entity and I don't need it).
Question: How can I get this class using mapstruct (DTO)

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users .......", nativeQuery = true)
List<Tuple> getInfo();

@Data
public class UserPro {
String login;
String email;
String pass;
Date regDate;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code base?

Comment: Nothing, I have no ideas

Comment: Not good, because this community doens't like such questions . You should post at least a code snippet, which can a volunter takes as start.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but you have some misunderstood concept. If i understood what you are asking...

The "getInfo" query has to obtain every "user" it receives from the query. Everything it receives it's been saved into a "Tuple" List, I suppose Tuple is a model or dto. If you want to save what you receive from that query you have to create a model, not a dto and you may call it "user".

Dtos are classes made to work with data relationated to a Http request, not a query.
Models are classes made to work with data relationated to a database, including database queries.

Inside that "user" model you have to instantiate every column you get from the database (be sure to name the @Column annotation variable the same each column is named on the database and give them the correct data type as in the Database).

Keep in mind that every user has an unique identifier, it doesn't have to be called ID, but you have to know who that unique identifier is.

After instantiating every variable you have to instantiate the getters and setters and a constructor instantiating every variable.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PUT_HERE_YOUR_UNIQUE_INDENTIFIER_HERE")
    private "UNIQUE_INDENTIFIER_DATA_TYPE" id;
    
    @Column(name = "LOGIN_COLUMN_NAME")
    private String login;
    
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD_COLUMN_NAME")
    private String pass;
    
    @Column(name = "REGDATE_COLUMN_NAME", nullable = false)
    private Date regDate;

    //default constructor
    public User() {}

    //user constructor
    public User()
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.login = login;
        this.email = email;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.regDate = regDate;
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login)
    {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPass()
    {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass)
    {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public Date getRegDate()
    {
        return regDate;
    }

    public void setRegDate(Date regDate)
    {
        this.regDate = regDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that you can just use entity and I can do it, but I need an implementation for a native query with mapstruct

Comment: Oh, I cannot help you with that. Never used mapstruct. I'm sorry.